# Ways to access class variable in method - python

Tags: python, oop, class-variables

Can you please tell me what is a difference between calling Class_name.class_variable and self.class_variable inside method. Here is the example:

```
class Employee:

   raise_amount = 1.04

   def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
       self.first = first
       self.last = last
       self.pay = pay

   def apply_raise(self):
       self.pay = int(self.pay * Employee.raise_amount)
```

So I used an Employee.raise_amount, but i can also write this method like that:

```
def apply_raise(self):
    self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount)
```

I tested that with:

```
emp_1 = Employee('James', 'Amb', 10000)
emp_2 = Employee('Test', 'User', 20000)

print("Original value")
print("emp_1.raise_amount", emp_1.raise_amount)
print("emp_2.raise_amount", emp_2.raise_amount)

emp_1.raise_amount = 1.1
print("emp_1.raise_amount = 1.1")
print("emp_1.raise_amount", emp_1.raise_amount)
print("emp_2.raise_amount", emp_2.raise_amount)

Employee.raise_amount = 1.2
print("Employee.raise_amount = 1.2")
print("emp_1.raise_amount", emp_1.raise_amount)
print("emp_2.raise_amount", emp_2.raise_amount)
```

I run the program using Employee.raise_amount and then self.raise_amount. In both situation OUTPUT is the same:

```
Original value
emp_1.raise_amount 1.04
emp_2.raise_amount 1.04
emp_1.raise_amount = 1.1
emp_1.raise_amount 1.1
emp_2.raise_amount 1.04
Employee.raise_amount = 1.2
emp_1.raise_amount 1.1
emp_2.raise_amount 1.2
```

So what is a difference and when should I use Class_name.class_variable and self.class_variable

Comment: Class_name.class_variable is called class variable which is owned by the class and self.class_variable is an instance variable, owned by an instance of a class. Because a class variable is shared by instances of a class, sometimes used to reduce repetition within code, helpful to adheres your code to the DRY principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python attribute reading, with `self.attribute` works like this:

1. Python checks if the attribute is a data descriptor in the class or ancestor class, if so, its `__get__` method is called (not the case, I will get back here later)
2. Then checks the instance (self) `__dict__` attribute, and sees if it contains `attribute`, if so, its fetched
3. checks if there is a "non data descriptor" (a descriptor without the `__set__` method, such as a function or method)
4. Then checks if it is a plain (non descriptor) attribute in the class `__dict__` **<- you are here!**
5. Checks for a plain attribute in any of the ancestor classes
6. Calls `__gettattr__` method on the class if it exists
7. Raises attribute error.

This set of rules is actually rather natural when one is making use of the language. But you have to take care if at any point you are *writting* back to the attribute - if you do something like `self.attribute = value`, then the attribute is set in the instance, not on the class, and if in other method you are retrieving it by doing `ClassName.attribute` it will see the orignal value, set on the class, not the value set on `self`, even if it is the same instance.

All things considered, the natural design of always using `self.attribute` will work better for read-only class attributes. If you need a special value for a single instance, you can set a new value for that instance only, and everything keeps working. For an example using your case, let's say that for most employees, the raise_ammount is 1.04, but one of them is special cased to be 1.06, any method or even external code can set the new attribute on the instance, and methods reading the value from `self.` will peek the updated number.

As for "descriptors" - they are special objects bound to the class that feature one of `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__` methods, and override attribute access on the instance and class. They are the mechanism used by the `@property` decorator, and by methods and classmethods themselves (so that the language can insert the `self` parameter in method calls).

Oh, and all these steps are encoded in the language in `object.__getattribute__` method (not the same as `__getattr__`). Any class that overrides `__getattribute__` can rewrite these rules at will (usually one will only tweak access to certain attributes, in order to create a proxy object, or something similar, not come out with a full hierarchical set of rules nearly as complex)

Answer (score 1):

One plays nice with inheritance, the other doesn't.

```py
class Base:
    a = 1

    def f(self):
        print(Base.a)


class Foo(Base):
    a = 2

Base().f()
Foo().f()
```

outputs

```
1
1
```

Changing `print(Base.a)` to `print(self.a)` changes the output to

```
1
2
```

because now `self` is an instance of `Foo` (so it refers to `Foo.a`) where `Base.a` unsurprisingly refers to `Base.a`, regardless of the current instance we use to call `f`.

Comment: The disadvantage of `self.a` is that it is ambiguous. It sometimes refers to the instance variable and sometimes to the class variable (if the instance variable is not set).  In most cases the ambiguity is ok. It is a feature.  However, if you want to be access the class variable SPECIFICALLY in a way that plays nice with inheritance, you can use `self.__class__.a`